# Cannot turn off my Macbook Pro (always reboot)

Tags: macbook-pro, reboot

My Macbook Pro 2020 cannot be turned off. If I shut it down normally, smoothly, it will reboot 5 seconds after being off. Even if I hold the power button for 10 seconds, it shuts down but immediately reboots.

The only solution I found is to wait until the battery is dead but it's not really a viable solution.

Do you see any other way I can turn this computer off?
Do you have any idea what could force the reboot of the laptop?

Comment: What version of MacOS are you running? (Click on the  (Apple) logo in the top left corner, and then "About this Mac")

Comment: @Harcker Version 11.6 (20G165)